# How do I change rows of an array from a 1D vector with specific positions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have the following arrays `a` and `b`

```
a = array([[ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 3,  4,  5],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 9, 10, 11]])

b = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 6,  7,  8],
   [ 0, 0, 0]])
```

and I have 1D array with specific rows that contains values 0 in a

```
c = array([0, 2])
```

Is there any way to merge the values of the two arrays using the rows of `c` without using a loop?

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: no, didn't work

Comment: ok, can you be specific when you say merge? you can add the expected output also

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to join the two arrays, using the rows of `c` without a loop and my expected output is
`a = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])`

Comment: That's the output my solution gives. So, I'm not entirely sure what is wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, the output is as follows `>>> a[c] = b[c]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
`

Comment: The variables `a` and `b` that you have are not numpy ndarrays. Just make sure you've ndarrays.

Comment: thanks for helping me this stupid question! it's solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this simple assignment?

```
a[c] = b[c]
```

Sample run:

```
In [226]: a[c] = b[c]

In [227]: a
Out[227]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```